# What is a shorthand way of displaying message and exiting on failure

Tags: bash, shell, exit, boolean-logic

Is there a quick line to displaying a message and exit on error? I usually use a line like so

```
sudo apt-get install time-machine || exit -1
```

But If I add a print statement like so, it will exit every time (`apt-get` will fail, the `echo` statement is printed, then the `exit -1` statement is called).

```
sudo apt-get install time-machine || echo "Time Travel is Impossible" ; exit -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group the commands so that they're executed in one shot.

```
sudo apt-get install time-machine || { echo "Time Travel is Impossible" ; exit -1 ; }
```

The final semicolon is important, as are the spaces around the braces; don't forget them.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also mention that it is important to have a space inside the curly brackets.

Comment: Also, does this cause any complications like how `(...)` sometimes runs a subshell where the variables declared in it can't escape upon completion

Comment: A reference in case anyone wants to read further https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: `echo "Time Travel is Impossible" >&2` or `printf '%s\n' "Time Travel is Impossible" >&2` is even better - so that the error is written to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: `echo $"Time Travel is Impossible" >&2`, because i18n matters.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is a function similar to:

```
die() {
  echo "$*" >&2       # Write message to stderr
  exit 1              # Exit with failure
}

sudo apt-get install time-machine || die "Time Travel is impossible"
```

Or when a different exit code is desired for different errors:

```
die() {
  echo "${*:2}" >&2   # Write params 2+ to stderr
  exit "$1"           # Exit with first parameter
}

sudo apt-get install time-machine || die 4 "Time Travel is impossible"
```

PS: Note that exit codes can't be negative: `-1` wraps to `255`.

Comment: A nicer definition is `printf "%s\n" "$@"`; it's trivial to pass a single argument to `die` if you want to, but using `printf` and multiple arguments provides the option of simple multi-line error messages without having to embed newlines in the argument; you just pass one argument per line.